# To focus on a component containing an input

Tags: angular, focus

I have a my-input component from the library. It's just a wrapper for input. How can I do the focus if I press span?

```
<div>
 <span (click)="onClickHandler();></span>
 <my-input #myinput></my-input>
</div>
```

this.myinput.nativeElement.focus() doesn't work

Comment: Did you try to use tabindex in your html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First pass read argument to ViewChild to get component ElementRef

```
 @ViewChild('myinput',{read:ElementRef}) myInput:ElementRef;
```

Then use `querySelector` on `nativeElement` to access the input element which is inside the `my-input` component

```
onClickHandler(){
    this.myInput.nativeElement.querySelector('input').focus();
  }
```

**[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wsvnvu?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**